# MFC CListCtrl displaying a textbox over a cell for user edit

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl where I display a textbox over a cell to allow the user to edit the cell's text.

This works, but I don't think the textbox will stay at the right location for different UI styles, based on user windows settings.

Does anyone know of a reliable way to center the textbox window over the cell the user clicked? Here is the code I am using now. I am not concerned about the right side of the textbox where I add the value 16. I only want a reliable way to get where to put the left and top of the textbox.

```
void FilesDialog::OnNMClickFiles(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMITEMACTIVATE temp = (LPNMITEMACTIVATE)pNMHDR;
    //get the row number
    nItem = temp->iItem;
    //get the column number
    nSubItem = temp->iSubItem;
    if (nSubItem == 0 || nSubItem == -1 || nItem == -1)
    {
        *pResult = 0;
        return;
    }
    //Retrieve the text of the selected subItem from the list
    CString str = GetItemText(filesList.m_hWnd, nItem, nSubItem);
    CRect rectList, rectDlg, rectCl;
    CRect rectItem;
    // Get the rectangle of the selected sub-item.
    ListView_GetSubItemRect(filesList.m_hWnd, temp->iItem, temp->iSubItem, LVIR_BOUNDS, &rectItem);
    //Get the Rectange of the listControl
    ::GetWindowRect(temp->hdr.hwndFrom, &rectList);
    //Get the Rectange of the Dialog
    ::GetWindowRect(this->m_hWnd, &rectDlg);
    GetClientRect(&rectCl);
    //this->ScreenToClient(&rectCl);
    int subY = rectDlg.Height() - rectCl.Height() - 5;
    int lft = rectItem.left + rectList.left - rectDlg.left + 1;
    int tp = rectItem.top + rectList.top - rectDlg.top - subY;
    // When an item is cut off by the window on the right
    // side, resize the text box so that the right side
    // is at the edge of the list control.
    int rtEdge = rectDlg.right - (rectDlg.right - rectCl.right);
    int subWdth = 0;
    if (lft + rectItem.Width() - 2 > rtEdge)
    {
        // 16 is just an arbitrary value that seems to work.
        subWdth = 16 + (lft + rectItem.Width() - 2) - rtEdge;
    }
    // Move the edit box window over the cell.
    editText.MoveWindow(lft, tp, rectItem.Width() - 2 - subWdth, rectItem.Height() - 1, true);
    //Set the list Item text in the edit box.
    ::SetWindowText(editText.m_hWnd, str);
    // Show the edit box and set focus to it.
    ::ShowWindow(editText.m_hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    ::SetFocus(editText.m_hWnd);

    *pResult = 0;

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how `editText` was created. If the parent of `editText` is the ListView control, for example:

```
editText.Create(WS_CHILD, CRect(0, 0, 1, 1), &filesList, 1);
```

Then there is no need to adjust anything, simply use `rectItem` as is:

```
void FilesDialog::OnNMClickFiles(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMITEMACTIVATE temp = (LPNMITEMACTIVATE)pNMHDR;
    if (temp->iSubItem == 0 || temp->iSubItem == -1 || temp->iItem == -1)
    {
        *pResult = 0;
        return;
    }

    CString str = filesList.GetItemText(temp->iItem, temp->iSubItem);

    CRect rectItem;
    filesList.GetSubItemRect(temp->iItem, temp->iSubItem, LVIR_BOUNDS, rectItem);

    editText.SetWindowText(str);
    editText.MoveWindow(rectItem, 1);
    editText.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

If on the other hand `editText`'s parent is not the ListView control, then the editbox will not position itself relative to ListView, therefore its position must be adjusted.

For example if `editText` was initialized in `DoDataExchange` then offset `rectItem` as follows:

```
POINT p = { 0 };
filesList.MapWindowPoints(this, &p, 1);
rectItem.OffsetRect(p.x, p.y);
...
editText.MoveWindow(rectItem, 1);
```